# Play Framework: package play.db.jpa not found

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to create a play 2.3.4 application with Spring Data JPA. [This](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1.1/guide2) tutorial says it is good practice to let my model class inherit from `play.db.jpa.Model`. Therefore I added `import play.db.jpa.*` to my code and let my model class to extend from `Model`, However, when I reloaded the application, I got an error message, that `Model` is an unknown symbol. Anybody
knows how to inherit from `Model`?

Comment: if you're using Play v2.x please don't refer to links for Play v1.x. Maybe the equivalent page for v2.x makes it clear what you need to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`play.db.jpa.Model` does not exists in Play2 (there is only a Model class for Ebean ORM). So dont extend that class. In fact for what I can tell, even on Ebean, extending it does not bring any improvement.

Also check that you have in your `libraryDependencies` (build.sbt file) the following entries

```
javaJpa,
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.6.Final"
```

(you can replace the second with a different implementation/version if you need). After that you can run `activator update` in the terminal.

Using Play1 instructions in Play2 will not work in many cases. Play1 and Play2 are two very different frameworks. The page you are looking for is probably [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA).