# Model superclass for JPA in Play Framework in 2.3.x Java

Tags: postgresql, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to use JPA in Play Framework for Java version 2.3.7.

Before in Play 1.x, there was a Model superclass that made it really easy to execute queries like "List persons = Person.findAll();".

Is there Model superclass for javaJpa to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `play.db.jpa.Model` class for Play 2

But you can use `play.db.jpa.JPA`

and to find all do

```
JPA.em().createQuery("select p from Person p").getResultList();
```

where the create query contains JPQL and Person is entity name .

For more details check [sample/computer-database-jpa](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/samples/java/computer-database-jpa).

Also check [Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/JavaJPA),[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957138/play-framework-package-play-db-jpa-not-found)

Comment: Except that you should put "SELECT order " in front of that otherwise it is ILLEGAL JPQL

Comment: @NeilStockton I am not an expert in JPQL but this query worked for me [Sample](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/app/models/Company.java)

Comment: What "works" on Hibernate is *not* what is JPQL standard (what you have there is HQL). Try that on other JPA implementations and it won't, so best get used to writing valid JPQL if portability is even a potential consideration

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no `play.db.jpa.Model` on play 2.

The closest thing should be Ebean and SpringJPA which I use and recommend because of Ebean being soon [removed in favor of JPA](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11sVi1-REAIDFVHvwBrfRt1uXkBzROHQYgmcZNGJtDnA/pub) and being JPA mature and well documented.

As a quick example, those should look like:

**Ebean**

FindAllUsage

```
List<Person> people = Person.find.all();
```

Person model

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model
{
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String value;

  public static final Model.Finder<Long, UserPermission> find =
    new Model.Finder<Long, UserPermission>(Long.class,UserPermission.class);

}
```

**SpringJPA**

FindAllUsage

```
List<Person> people = personRepository.findAll();
```

Person repository

```
@Named
@Singleton
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Agent,Long> {
}
```

Person model

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2 the Model class is extending Ebean ORM by default and it has these general methods as `save, update, find.byId, find.all` etc.